# Fail over from Azure VM to Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, automatic-failover

We want to fail over from **Azure VM** (Windows Server) to **Azure Web App**. VM hosts the web application, and Web App is just a page informing Website Under Maintenance message. This is for planned/un-planned maintenance events of the server.
Once the maintenance is over, how to retract it back.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like a simple 302 (temp redirect) is a fairly common approach, or changing the host name your dns entry points to. Not sure exactly what you're looking for here...

Comment: Thanks David. What we want is : when web application (say www.abc.com hosted in VM) is under maintenance, all request to this web app (www.abc.com) should render content from another Azure website (say www.xyz.com). This website (xyz.com) will have one single page informing that the web site is under maintenance. Once we are done with maintenance, requests to abc.com would resume serving contents from it's own hosted site, not from the one hosted in xyz.com. How do we achieve this in Azure? Thanks.